# Overflow-y does not work in textarea

Tags: html, css, sass

I have issue with `overflow-y` property in my form. When  I added this property to my **SCSS** nothing changed. I also added `height` and `max-height` property and I still cannot get the proper result.

Here is my code:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="What is your name?">
  <input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="Type your e-mail">
  <input type="textarea" name="message" placeholder="Leave your message here">
</form>
```

**SCSS**

```
form {
  input[type="text"],
  input[type="textarea"] {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 5vh;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    &:focus {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
  }
  input[type="text"] {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5vh;
  }
  input[type="textarea"] {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20vh;
    max-height: 20vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vmzmz1ru/

Comment: the jsfiddle working correctly on Chrome

Comment: why dont you use <textarea></textarea> tag ..  <input type="textarea" /> is invalid i suppose.

Comment: It does not work in Firefox, and I am trying to fix it...

Comment: What behaviour are you expecting? As Sahil stated, <input type="textarea" /> is not a valid element. Input fields are single line elements. Use <textarea></textarea> instead.

Comment: For one, there is no such thing as `input` with `type="textarea"`. The element you want is called `textarea`, as in `<textarea>Hello world.</textarea>`.

Answer (score 4):

Please correct

```
<input type="textarea">
```

Is not a valid tag. If you want a `textarea` you need to create the tag like this:

```
<textarea> </textarea>
```

and in CSS selector also you need to write the selector like this:

```
textarea{
 /* CSS code here */
}
```

Comment: and add these  styles
white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;

Answer (score 1):

use `<textarea></textarea>` tag .. `<input type="textarea" />` is invalid

> Here is the updated working fiddle:
>   https://jsfiddle.net/doddw147/